# Jetty temp directory with multiple instances

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am having multiple jetty server instances to a load balancer. 
 I am setting the following temp directory in jetty.xml

```
 <Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>javax.servlet.context.tempdir</Arg>
    <Arg>/some/dir/foo</Arg>
  </Call>

Can multiple servers instances point to the same temp directory?
```

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/ref-temporary-directories.html#_setting_a_specific_temp_directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple server instances can point to the same temp directory. If you are trying to pull something from what directory I'd recommend persisting the temp directory as explained in the documentation you linked.